# Does a horse come with the wagon or need to be purchased separately?

Tags: dnd-4e, vehicles

In the Player's Handbook, you're given the option to buy a cart/wagon. Do you need to buy a horse as well or does it come with a horse?

Comment: There's no stupid questions here. :) D&D's a complex game to learn and answers aren't always clear.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3):

### You'll have to provide your own animal(s).

The 20-gp wagon is further detailed in the *Adventurer's Vault* supplement, which expanded the rules for mounts and vehicles. If you don't have that available to you, a summary of the changes to the PHB-relevant rules:

- it can be pulled by 1, 2, or 4 Large creatures. 1 Huge creature can stand in for 2 Large creatures.
- when pulled by 1 Large creature, its speed is (the speed of the Large creature - 6).
- when pulled by 2 Large creatures or the equivalent, its speed is (the speed of the slowest creature - 4).
- when pulled by 4 Large creatures or the equivalent, its speed is (the speed of the slowest creature - 2).
- the cargo capacity is now 4 tons, in addition to 4 medium creatures, but keep in mind the total pull capacity of whatever you're using to pull it.